# Creating Custom Shipping Method In Magento, Weight vs Destination and Zones?

Tags: php, magento

am just switching from my e-commerce shopping basket website to a Magento implementation.

Currently we have different Shipping Zones for different countries, and the weight of the final shopping basket determines the Shipping Price for the selected country. We therefore just have one shipping method, i.e. "Standard Shipping".

What I would like to do is use the Country Code to carry out a lookup and locate the Postal Zone and use that Postal Zone to lookup/calculate the Shipping Price of the basket based on it's weight.

Have seen a few examples of Flat Rates, but not too sure if they are applicable?

*I don't have the finances to buy an extension as yet.*

Thank you for any help or advice,

Barton.

Answer (score 0):

This extension does exactly what you need and its free.
[Matrixrate](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension.html)

All you have to do is export the CSV file and map all your shipping methods accordingly to the location, weight and price. It also allows you to create custom free deliveries over an amount.

Comment: Thanks for the heads upon this plugin. Not too sure that it does what I need without paying for the 'Pro' version. I have 5 Postal Zones which each contain a list of countries that share the same postal costs for different weights. All I require is that I intercept the call to calculate the postal cost, based upon weight, and return the postal cost to Magento. Can this plugin do that? Thank you so much again, Barton.

Comment: UPDATE: Just had a message from the Development Team and I would require the Premium Version @damek132.